# Why is “l'obtint” used here instead of “s'obtint”?

Tags: choix-de-mot, pronoms, verbes-pronominaux

Below is the quote from ***Le Mariage de Figaro***:

> Il fallait un calculateur, ce fut un danseur qui ***l'obtint***.

So the author was intended to express that a dancer was employed or obtained in a passive voice, right? Why not s'obtint? Please explain it to me in English, many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Le désespoir m'allait saisir ; on pense à moi pour une place, mais par malheur j'y étais propre : il fallait un calculateur, ce fut un danseur qui l'obtint.

Ce fut un danseur qui obtint la **place de calculateur**.
→ 
Ce fut un danseur qui **l**'obtint.

*l'* is the direct object personal pronoun that stands for *la place de calculateur*.

<sub>(A dancer got the job (it), (and not Figaro).</sub>

There is no passive voice in that sentence. The verb used is *obtenir*. We would have a passive voice with the verb ***s***'obtenir(reflexive) in for example:

> Ce travail *s'obtient* sans qualification.

which means the same as:

> Ce travail *est obtenu* sans qualification.

<sub>(You can get this job without qualification.)</sub>

Comment: @Lambie The word *le* is a personal pronoun. (There are several words spelled *le*, the one in this sentence is the one that is a personal pronoun.) Its function in the sentence is a direct object.

Comment: @Gilles Je le sais, Et je vous dis à tous les deux, en anglais on dit: direct object pronoun. On ne dit pas: object personal pronoun. Voilà, c'est tout. Et je m'excuse d'avoir parlé de faute orthographique....

Comment: @Lambie Don't say  *en anglais **o**n dit* ou ***we** say* because you do not represent the English language all to yourself. "Quirk" has of course ***personal** pronouns*, a lot of grammar books use the terms of [object personnal pronouns](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WCCk829jmzUC&pg=PA670&lpg=PA670&dq=%22object+personal+pronoun%22+english&source=bl&ots=iIUYx3lyfq&sig=kz5RSRFyabSBYD481mPhDUbmwSI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj84Z_1gfrUAhWSZVAKHbGkA9s4ChDoAQhMMAY#v=onepage&q=%22object%20personal%20pronoun%22%20english&f=false)

Comment: or [subject personal pronouns](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-personal-i-me-you-him-it-they-etc). Other sorts of pronouns can be subjects or objects in the sentence... "Mine is very old", "I like that/yours" "What are you saying?" "Don't tell anyone" etc.

Comment: @Laure Can't argue with perfection. If that is what one is striving for, no matter the method.